# Trigger grunt task after browserify/watchify run

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, watchify

I'm trying to build my JS-bundle via grunt/browserify. I also use grunt for scss compile. For that I use grunt-watch to trigger scss compile on changes.

I wanted the same behavior for JS-browserify. grunt-browserify comes with the "watch" option, which does the trick very well.

My only issue is: I want to get notified after a "re-browserify". For SCSS I use grunt-notify. But I do not find any way to trigger a grunt task after browserify-watch.

My gruntfile excerpt:

```
var gruntOptions = {

    notify: {
        browserify_node_modules: {
            options: {
                title: "Browserify",
                message: "node_modules build"
            }
        }
    },

    browserify: {
        node_modules: {
            src: ["node_modules.js"],
            dest: "trunk/js/lib/node_modules.js",
            options: {
                watch: true,
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Best case scenario:

```
            options: {
                watch: true,
                finishTask: "notify:browserify_node_modules"
            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file generated by Browserify has been changed and then, trigger a task.

Install `watch` task in Grunt:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
```

Configure `watch` task within `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    // other tasks

    your_task: {
        // ...
    },

    watch: {
        dev: {
            files: 'trunk/js/lib/node_modules.js', // file generated by Browserify
            options: { spawn: false },
            tasks: ['your_task']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```